# select all fields from ilist, contains list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, ilist

I have an IList--->

```
IList<Test> list;
```

the list contains objects of the class Test, given below:

```
list.Add(new Test{ id = 1, name = "abc" })
list.Add(new Test{ id = 2, name = "xyz" })
list.Add(new Test{ id = 3, name = "nmo" })
```

where class Test is --->

```
Class Test
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

Now I want to **select all name fields** (of all elements of list)--->

```
IList<string> nameList = ???
```

I got stuck in this (lack of knowledge about LINQ c#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IList<string> nameList = YourCollection.Select(item=> item.name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

```
 nameList = list.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```